# Merging files by name and condition in r

Tags: r

I have a series of files in a folder that look like this;

> B_1.csv, B_1_2.csv, B_2.csv, B_2_2.csv, B_3.csv, B_4.csv, B_4_1.csv

Basically, I wish to merge any files which contain '_2' to their proceeding number (i.e. B_1_2.csv merges with B_1.csv). A further complication is that some files (such as B_3.csv) do not have a second file (_2) and therefore need to be ignored. I cannot think of an easy way of completing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: *"merge any files which contain '_2' to their proceeding number"*, so, `B_2.csv` contains `"_2"`, does it get merged with `B_1.csv` along with `B_1_2.csv`?

Comment: If that's not what you want, a nice way to make answer simpler might be to remove the first `_` in file names, or perhaps replace it with a `-`. `oldnames = list.files(pattern = ".csv$"); newnames = sub("_", "-", oldnames); file.rename(from = oldnames, to = newnames)`

Comment: To clarify I wish to indeed bind the dataframes together rowwise. When i say "merge any files which contain '_2' to their proceeding number"- i mean proceeding number within the filename. For example; B_1_2.csv binds to the bottom of B_1.csv, B_2_2.csv binds to the bottom of B_2.csv

Comment: Hi @PhilRoberts, thanks for clarifying. In that case my answer requires some tweaks which I currently haven't got the time to do. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, of course, but this should work (or something close to it):

```
# identify CSV files
files = list.files(pattern = "csv$")

# look for ones that need merging
to_merge = grep("[0-9]_2\\.csv", files, value = TRUE)
# identify what they should be merged to
merge_target_file = sub("_2.csv", ".csv", to_merge, fixed = TRUE)

# make sure those exist
problems = setdiff(merge_target_file, files)
if(length(problems)) stop(problems, " not found, need merge targets.")

# read in the data
merge_target = lapply(merge_target_file, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
to_merge = lapply(to_merge, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# merge and write
for(i in seq_along(merge_target)) {
  write.csv(rbind(merge_target[[i]], to_merge[[i]]), file = merge_target_file[i])
}
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, i've been attempting to implement this but have discovered a few problems. Firstly, i assume 'files' should be included in the 'sub' function- only x is not present currently. Secondly, grep in this case only returns the chronological order of the '_2' in the list e.g. int [1-8]  5 7 10 12 14 16 19 21. Wouldn't;  to_merge = list.files (pattern = "_2") be more suitable? Many thanks

Comment: Fixed it up, added `value = TRUE` to `grep` so it returns the file name, and added `to_merge` as an argument of `sub`. You could skip the `grep` step by using `"[0-9]_2\\.csv"` as the `list.files` pattern, but then you don't get the "make sure those exist" opportunity to check that the merge targets already exist.